# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application with JDK 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

I'm trying to run the sample JavaFX project using IntelliJ but it fails with the exception :

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I have downloaded JDK 11 here : http://jdk.java.net/11/
I have downloaded OpenJFX here : http://jdk.java.net/openjfx/
I'm using : IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.3684.40, built on July 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

I have created a new JavaFX project in IntelliJ using JDK 11. My JavaFX classes were not known so I have added the OpenJFX library by doing :

- File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> + -> Library -> Java

I have the OpenJFX added with the 8 jars below "classes" and also the folders below "Sources" and the path to the bin folder under "Native Library Locations".

When I'm building the project, it's good, but impossible to run it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this [getting started](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafx11/) guide. See all the required configuration to compile and run your sample. Note also that you can add the JavaFX dependencies directly from Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks I've followed it and it' actually working. Pretty odd that I cannot launch it directly from IntelliJ...

Comment: Good to know. Everything is EA yet, but if you can run modules from your IDE, you should be able to config the project to run it. Did you try it using the pom.xml?

Comment: Yes indeed I've made a Maven Project but impossible to run it through IntelliJ, only from the CommandLine.

Comment: being on eclipse, with a similar problem (slightly different context): adding both --module-path and --add-module as vm args for the installed jre helped

Comment: @kleopatra What if you put them on the classpath and not on the module path (in a non-modular project)?

Comment: @user1803551 I need them on the module path to tweak the modules (open for internal access) - that's working okay, except for a bug in eclipse that doesn't copy them over correctly to the runtime environment https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534572

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install openjfx

Comment: I recently ran into this problem with a Java 17 app in IntelliJ. I noticed that if you make the application modular by adding a module-info file, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 110):

This worked for me:

> File >> Project Structure >> Modules >> Dependency >> + (on left-side of window)

clicking the "+" sign will let you designate the directory where you have unpacked JavaFX's "lib" folder.

Scope is Compile (which is the default.)
You can then edit this to call it JavaFX by double-clicking on the line.

then in:

> Run >> Edit Configurations

Add this line to VM Options:

```
--module-path /path/to/JavaFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

(oh and don't forget to set the SDK)

Comment: JavaFX 11 is no longer bundled with JDK , it builds on top of JDK 11 and is a standalone component. Just see this video on how to integrate them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno

You need to download the stand-alone JavaFx here >>>> https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Cheers

Comment: @Fanadez the video contains the precise steps infact, kudos!

Comment: If you use Eclipse, please make sure, to also deacitvate the ()Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argumemt when launching with SWT, otherwise efforts to use JavaFX will not not be proccessed . :)

Comment: The set-up instructions tell you to use the VM Options line from your answer on the command line. It absolutely did not work for me, but using the NetBeans "Edit Configurations" menu really worked. Thank you!

Comment: `--add-modules=javafx.controls` gave me **java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found**

Comment: Based on official docs, you also need to add `javafx.fxml` to command args

Comment: *java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found* for me too

Comment: `--module-path /path/to/JavaFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` ..... just add the `javafx.fxml` if you're working with fxml.

Comment: See my answer at the topic by link in the header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11 to make your solution complete, don't forget exports.

Comment: ok... and what if we use a build tool like literally every other developer with a brain...?