# MathML tags don't render properly in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8, mathml, javafx-webengine

MathML tags don't render properly in JavaFX WebView

JDK Version : 1.8.0_192

For example,

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"> 
   <msub> 
    <mi>
      S 
    </mi> 
    <mi>
      n 
    </mi> 
   </msub> 
   <mo>
     &lt; 
   </mo> 
   <mstyle displaystyle="true" scriptlevel="0"> 
    <mfrac> 
     <mi>
       π 
     </mi> 
     <mrow> 
      <mn>
        3 
      </mn>     
      <msqrt> 
       <mn>
         3 
       </mn> 
      </msqrt> 
     </mrow> 
    </mfrac> 
   </mstyle> 
 </math>
```

The above code renders as:

[image: Chrome rendering]

in Google Chrome, while it renders as:

[image: WebView version]

in JavaFX WebView.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result on my computer with the code you posted ? ?

[image: Screenshot CaptainIRS MathML Code]

First, be sure you're using at least Java/JavaFX 8 192 build 04 or JavaFX 11 (MathML support is broken, in Java/JavaFX 9 and 10 and won't be fixed in these versions).

Secondly, verify your font list. May be a font config issue on your computer ?

At least one of these fonts must be installed (in order of preference):

- `Latin Modern Math`
- `STIX Two Math`
- `XITS Math`
- `STIX Math`
- `Libertinus Math`
- `TeX Gyre Termes Math`
- `TeX Gyre Bonum Math`
- `TeX Gyre Schola`
- `DejaVu Math TeX Gyre`
- `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`
- `Asana Math`
- `Cambria Math`
- `Lucida Bright Math`
- `Minion Math`
- `Times New Roman`

The result on my computer too, but after `Latin Modern Math` font installation :

[image]

Code example : did you use a code like this ?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NavigateurTest extends Application {

    final StackPane root = new StackPane();
    final WebView webView =  new WebView();
    String ContentStackOverFlow = ""
            + "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">"
            + "   <msub>"
            + "      <mi>S</mi>"
            + "      <mi>n</mi>"
            + "   </msub>"
            + "   <mo>&lt;</mo>"
            + "   <mstyle displaystyle=\"true\" scriptlevel=\"0\">"
            + "      <mfrac>"
            + "         <mi>π</mi>"
            + "         <mrow>"
            + "            <mn>3</mn>"
            + "            <msqrt>"
            + "               <mn>3</mn>"
            + "            </msqrt>"
            + "         </mrow>"
            + "      </mfrac>"
            + "   </mstyle>"
            + "</math>";

    public void init() {    
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //webView.getEngine().load("https://www.qwant.com");
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(ContentStackOverFlow);

        primaryStage.setTitle("OpenJFX MathML Rendering WebBrowser Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, there seems to be a bug in the EA version which prevents IntelliJ from using OpenJDK 11. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51478675/9224581) Any workaround for this?

Comment: This is really far away from the subject you post first ? ? ?

Comment: It doesn't work either with jdk 8u192 build 4 with the said fonts installed.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your quest. MathML support is the same in JFX 8 and JFX 11. Actually, I started to work with JDK 11 and JFX 11 long time ago so I never use IDE because they were not ready to use JDK 11 and JFX11. Presently, I'm using a script with my own JFX build.

Comment: I tested it with Windows and Linux and the result is the same. What is your OS ?

Comment: I'm on Windows. I'm not quite experienced using command line. So I use an IDE.

Comment: It worked fine. So, probably there's a problem with my html file

Comment: @RinishSam Text blocks were introduced in JDK 13, and they'll probably help, since text blocks were just introduced so that developers could easily write multiline code without the concatenation stuff.