# How I can use the JavaFX framework?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

firstly, I want let you know how useful this community is for me, I was stuck on an error

```
`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`
```

and thanks to this answer I actually solved: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli)

However I've a couple of questions. I noticed that IntelliJ doesn't change the configurations (Like set the VM option and pick the right library for the javaFX project), so each time I've to create a new JavaFX11 or 12 project I've to being throw all the manually settings again. 
There's a way for set a "default behaviour" for the IDE ? It's really cumbersome.

The second question is, how I can use all the beautiful framework that the developer community offer for JavaFX? I've seen on [openjFX](https://openjfx.io) a couple of interesting framework like TilesFX or CalendarFX but there's no information on how implement them on my IDE neither on GitHub nor here. 
I have seen that most of them uses Gradle files, but honestly I don't have the faintest idea of what this kind of file does and how implement it on IntelliJ. Thank's to everybody.

Comment: See JavaFX and IntelliJ section at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ . You can edit the Template run/debug configuration so that you don't have to specify the options again.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I followed the instruction but I've to re-set again manually the configuration each time. I followed your link, but exactly which step I've to follow ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-default-run-debug-configurations.html

Answer (score 0):

Run the project with a more recent JDK like JDK11, for example.

If it does'nt work, you probably forgot to change the **JDK of your builder** in IntelliJ!

> Open the settings and follow the path as bellow:

`FOR MAVEN`
[image]

`FOR GRADLE`
[image]