# How do i fix the Error: JAVAFX runtime components are misssing, and are required to run this application?

Tags: java, javafx

Hello there i got a problem running my java and javafx files
I have installed Java and JDK
If i click on the Application simply nothing happens
When i Try to run i from my cmd this Shows up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GfT0.png)

I have searched through half of google but didnt find a solutions that worked for me.
It would be very very very nice if anybody could help me fix this problem since im a beginner at coding at all and just wanted tu run a simple WidgetShortcut application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application with JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text like exceptions and command line entries, instead copy the test and paste it into the question formatted as code.

Comment: See the Eden coding guide [runtime components are missing](https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/).

Answer (score 0):

They removed the JavaFX Components from JDK/JRE. You'll need to add them into your package.   See information here https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/