# java -jar HelloFX.jar is running on windows perfectly, but not running in Linux or Raspberry pi

Tags: java, linux, javafx, jar, raspberry-pi

Whenever I run java -jar HelloFX.jar command in Linux or raspberry pi, that application shows the error below, I'm searching for a solution  from the last month over the internet, but not finding any valid solution. But the Jar file is working in different windows with JDK 21. I've installed JDK 21 on Raspberry pi and my Linux too, other Java files are working well, but when I try to run JavaFX jar file, it's show these error.

```
jibon@jibon:~/Desktop $ java -jar HelloFX.jar 
Nov 27, 2023 1:24:11 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @9efff14'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

I've used IntelliJ IDE for building the JavaFX applications. As I told you, **it's working perfectly with different windows. But when I tried to run this on Linux or Raspberry Pi, it's shows me these errors.**
Please give me a perfect solution for this.

[image]

## Some files

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pro.jibon.apps.hellofx</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloFX</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx/pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx.Main
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx.Main</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**HelloApplication.java**

```
package pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TouchEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.io.IOException;


public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @FXML
    private Button button1;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), stage.getMaxWidth(), stage.getMaxHeight());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.show();
        button1 = (Button) scene.lookup("#btn");
        button1.setText("Close");
        button1.setOnAction(mouseEvent -> {
            stage.close();
        });
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Wait");
            alert.setContentText("Are feeling okay by clicking me huh?");
            alert.setHeaderText("WTF yaar!");
//            alert.show();
            windowEvent.consume();
        });
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            stage.setFullScreen(true);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public static boolean isRunningOnRaspberryPi() {
        try {
            GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
            gpio.shutdown();
            return true;
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**HelloView.FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.14-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
     <padding>
         <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
     </padding>
     <ToolBar nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <items>
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </items>
     </ToolBar>

     <Label fx:id="welcomeText" />
     <Button fx:id="btn" alignment="CENTER" text="Hello!">
      <effect>
         <Blend />
      </effect>
   </Button>
 </VBox>
```

**Main.java**

```
package pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx;

import pro.jibon.apps.hellofx.hellofx.*
        ;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloApplication.main(args);
    }
}
```

## Some necessary screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Output on Windows

[image]

## Output on Linux

[image]

Comment: You need to use the [JavaFX](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) that is compatible with the host operating system and architecture.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application with JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478675/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-appli).

Comment: Getting stuff to work on Pi is probably different.  Probably a totally different question (please keep questions focused).  There are probably articles around that describe that process, make sure you use ones that are use modern modular JavaFX distributions if you follow one.  There is [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/getting-started-with-javafx-on-raspberry-pi), but it is a bit dated.  Unforunately this [oracle guide](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/raspberrypifx/raspberryfx.html) is dated.

Comment: Gluon provide a [modern guide for JavaFX on embedded systems such as Pi](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_embedded).

Comment: Using `ea` distributions is not recommended.  They are early access distributions, not guaranteed to be stable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to add to your POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>{YOUR_VERSION}</version>
    <classifier>linux</classifier>
</dependency>
```